# Store an element with content in static resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I want to use this border in multiple places, but I don't want to have to copy/paste it multiple times. How would I define it in the `<Window.Resources>` so I could just reference it?

```
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1.5" Margin="5" Padding="0">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" Opacity="0.7">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Black"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
```

Thank you for any help...

Comment: do you mean you don't want to write `<Border... ` for every control? or do you just want share `<Border.BorderBrush>`

Comment: @LeiYang: Either or -- Just so I only have to add one line of XAML as opposed to all 9 that makes that Border look the way it does.

Comment: decorating any type of control, or limited kinds(such as button)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Resources you can keep style, and can apply that style to any control in your Window/User Control. So you can do

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1.5" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0" Opacity="0.7">
                <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Black"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and can use it like

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly.